# How can I fetch duplicate rows

Tags: sql, duplicates

Assuming I have a table like:

| ID | valA | valB | valC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | aaaaa | NYC |
| 4 | 12 | bbbbb | NYC |
| 2 | 31 | ddddd | LA |
| 2 | 23 | eeeee | LA |
| 2 | 41 | fffff | NE |
| 3 | 23 | ggggg | JE |
| 3 | 44 | hhhhh | KA |

I want to have all rows that have duplicate of valC.
So, as a result I would like to have this:

| ID | valA | valB | valC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | aaaaa | NYC |
| 4 | 12 | bbbbb | NYC |
| 2 | 31 | ddddd | LA |
| 2 | 23 | eeeee | LA |

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, count(valC) 
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B ON A.valC = B.valC
WHERE A.valC = B.valC AND valC > 1;
```

I am pretty new on SQL so I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An easy way to use [Subquery](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-subquery)

**This example is working in MySQL**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE valC IN ( SELECT valC 
                FROM table_name 
                GROUP BY valC 
                HAVING COUNT(valC) > 1);
```

Comment: Works also in other rdbms like sql-server

Comment: Thank you that works perfect. I have one more question.

Comment: Yes, you can ask.